# How to Create a travelling sine wave movement with `jradiobutton `

Tags: java, netbeans-8, waveform, trigonometry

I am using NetBeans8 IDE .

[Here is a fiddle by a programmer.](http://jsfiddle.net/twNcy/5/)

Here he create a sine wave movement with a box using `javascript`.After a long search I get the equation for SINE wave.But I tried a lot,But I cant get any result.

y = sin (kx − ωt)

My question is,

How create such travelling wave effect using a `jcomponent` like `JRadiobutton`

or

how we create the `x` and `y` co ordinates using this equation from -[ThisPHYSCLIPS Webpage](http://www.animations.physics.unsw.edu.au/jw/travelling_sine_wave.htm)

Kindly help me to solve this..Thanks in advance.

Here is my bit of code

```
Timer t = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {                                                                                           //        |
                                                                                                                                        //        |
    @Override                                                                                                                           //        |
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {            


            int xnow=AL1.getX()+1;
            int ynow=AL1.getY();
            ynow=(int) (ynow+Math.sin(2*Math.PI*(xnow/50))*10);

            AL1.setLocation(xnow, ynow);
        }                                                                                                                            //        |       


});  


private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    AL1.setLocation(0, 200);
    t.start();
}
```

But my `jRadioButton` is going some where..

Comment: Converting the JavaScript you posted to Java should be quite straight forward. Besides that have a look at any Swing animation tutorials.

Comment: I am working on it sir,But could you tell me how to makes x and y coordinates based on that equation

Comment: @AkhilVijay He did. If you lookup any swing animation tuts (there are more than we can link), you'll find the answer to your question.

Comment: Assuming you want your button to just move on the y-axis you still can use the code you linked - with a small modification: instead of the updated x-value that is used to calculate the y-value you set a constant x-coordinate for the button and then just keep updating the y-coordinate based on your calculation.

Comment: I edited my question with my code.Please check

Comment: helo sir,,Please check it out.